# facebook instagram webhook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

Trying to create an application to handle businesses installing my app and subscribing to mentions events.

I have set up the app correctly from what I can see, but when I get the token and then call the subscribe endge using the facebook page id and the page access token I do not get the expected response from facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/webhooks#install-app

According to this I should get a success response, but I just get empty data.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/{page-id}/subscribed_apps/?access_token={page-token}

```
{
   "data": []
}
```

The app is a test app, not yet live, does success only get returned if the app is actually live?

Would appreciate any insight into what I am getting wrong, I find the facebook documentation great in places and lacking in others.

Comment: Make the same request using POST, and check what response you get.

Comment: bingo, boy do I feel stupid!! I should have spotted that, thanks!!